# How do I get regain access to Xcode's "Round Button" item?

Tags: ios, xcode5

I am using Xcode 5.1.1 for iOS development and I saw something yesterday that I can't re-display.  In IB at the bottom right corner are the various items such as UISliders, code snippets, etc.  What I saw yesterday was a selection of things like "Round Button", "Radio Button Group", and many more useful looking things.  I tried dragging one into IB as well as into a source code file with no success.  What are they and how do I regain access to them?

Comment: It's easy enough to make a round button out of the button you get in iOS's IB. Set the button's `layer.cornerRadius' to a value like 50 or 100 or more, and adjust the width and the height to equal values.

Comment: Those appear if you don't have a scheme selected (or if you have an OS X scheme selected), but you can't actually use them on iOS.

Comment: Wasn't actually trying to make a round button...yet.  Thanks for the simple trick @GlennRay!

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you saw UI elements for OS X.  They aren't available for iOS, so when you have an iOS nib or storyboard open, they don't appear.

Comment: Figures - OSX stuff. Thanks for the response.